# Diferente forma de expresar una frase. Ya sea a través de sinónimos o alterando su orden

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Esta frase me suena muy rara. ¿Creen que hay una forma más entendible de expresar el mismo significado?

> Con el planteamiento apropiado, se podrá alcanzar el número 1 mundial
>   de manera indisputada. Sin olvidar el prestigio que se adquirirá de
>   cara a esta generación.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es frasearla como:

> *Con el plantamiento apropiado, se podrá alcanzar indiscutiblemente la primera posición a nivel mundial, sin olvidar el prestigio que se adquirirá frente a esta generación.*

Quizás también algo de contexto pueda ayudar.

Comment: Suena mejor. Tal vez "_de manera indisputada_" (que a mí me sigue sonando raro) se puede reemplazar por "_indiscutiblemente_".

Comment: @Rodrigo Sí, se ve mejor así.

Comment: O decirlo así:.._se podrá alcanzar la primera posición indisputada a nivel mundial, sin olvidar el prestigio_...

Comment: **"La primera posición indisputada"** quiere decir que no hay un rival al mismo nivel. **"Alcanzar indiscutiblemente la primera posición"** significa que sin lugar a discusión se alcanzará el primer puesto con o sin rivales que puedan disputar el título al mismo nivel. La respuesta de @Ustanak suena mucho mejor que la frase original (+1), pero el significado cambia un poquito.

Answer (score 0):

Yo propongo una ligera variación:

> Con el plantamiento adecuado, sin duda se alcanzaría la primera posición a nivel mundial, además del aumento de prestigio que se obtendría frente a esta generación.